# Repeat image inside rectangle

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, sprite-kit

Is there a way to repeat an UIImage inside a rectangle using CoreGraphics? It's kind of like http://www.raywenderlich.com/33496/core-graphics-tutorial-patterns, but I'm gonna use an image loaded from file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19490970/763355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the image as a pattern color:

```
UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:myImage];
someView.backgroundColor = color;
```

Not exactly Core Graphics, though. If you really need it there's `CGColorCreateWithPattern`. It's a bit more code to set up.

Comment: That's cool. I'm trying to make a SKTexture and/or SKSpriteNode out of it in the end and seeing as there is `[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:colorTest size:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];` I gave it a go, alas it doesn't seem to like a "image color".

Comment: @Jonny See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490970/sprite-kit-and-colorwithpatternimage/19833309#19833309