# How do you set a texture to tile in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am making a sprite kit game and it is obviously more efficient to have one big SKSpriteNode with a tiled texture, than having multiple SKSpriteNodes with the tile texture. My Problem is that when I try to make a 5x5 tile using

```
SKTexture* tex = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,5,5) inTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tile.png"]];
SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tex size:CGSizeMake(100,100)];
```

The image is re sized appropriately, but it is clamped and not tiled. In openGL terms I am getting a GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE where I want a GL_REPEAT. Is there anyway I could achieve the tiling effect of a texture in a single SKSpriteNode, without creating a very large image.

Here is an image of my problem:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Afaik, there is no way to create sprite with tiled texture. But what you can do, is render lot's of sprites in a single drawing pass.

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit/DesigningGameswithSpriteKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH7-SW7) (Sprite Kit Best Practices -> Drawing your content):

> If all of the children of a node use the same blend mode and texture
>   atlas, then Sprite Kit can usually draw these sprites in a single
>   drawing pass. On the other hand, if the children are organized so that
>   the drawing mode changes for each new sprite, then Sprite Kit might
>   perform as one drawing pass per sprite, which is quite inefficient.

Comment: Shader based implementation that uses just 1 node http://stackoverflow.com/a/37768928/763355

Answer (score 1):

Apply ciaffinetile filter when 
creating texture.

Answer (score 1):

```
SKTexture* tex = [SKTexture textureWithRect:CGRectMake(0,0,5,5) inTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tile.png"]];
```

The `textureWithRect:inTexture:` creates a subtexture, and the rectangle argument is in **unit coordinate space**, which means all values are 0-1

Behavior of `CGRectMake(0,0,5,5)` is non defined, but seems to be stretching the texture by a factor of 5.

---

**Edit**: Unit Coordinate Space

> You can think of the unit coordinates as specifying a percentage of the total possible value. Every coordinate in the unit coordinate space has a range of 0.0 to 1.0. For example, along the x-axis, the left edge is at the coordinate 0.0 and the right edge is at the coordinate 1.0. Along the y-axis, the orientation of unit coordinate values changes depending on the platform

[Core Animation Programming Guide, Layers Use Two Types of Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW15)

Comment: A belated thank you for this post - can you tell me where unit coordinate space is defined in Apple documentation?

Comment: @rswayz, Added description and link in answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the question not perfectly answered. I solved it this way.

You know you can do this in UIButton or UIImageView by resizableImageWithCapInsets ,so ,Here is my solution :

```
-(SKTexture *)textureWithImage:(UIImage *)image tiledForSize:(CGSize)size withCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets{
//get resizable image
image =  [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:capInsets];
//redraw image to target size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width-1, size.height-1)];
[[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
//get target image
UIImage *ResultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// get texture
SKTexture * texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:ResultImage];
return texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to help me convert coordinate systems, I use the following function - that way I can use the absolute coordinates like you did above with (5,5):

```
//Pass the absolute sizes of your sub-texture (subRect) and main-texture (mainRect)
CGRect unitCoordinateGivenSubRectInRect (CGRect subRect, CGRect mainRect)
{
if (mainRect.size.height == 0 || mainRect.size.width == 0) {
    return CGRectZero;
}

float x = subRect.origin.x / mainRect.size.width;
float y = subRect.origin.y / mainRect.size.height;

float sizeX = subRect.size.width / mainRect.size.width;
float sizeY = subRect.size.height / mainRect.size.height;

return CGRectMake(x, y, sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 薛永伟’s answer, and translated it to Swift in an extension:

```
extension SKTexture {

  static func x_repeatableTexture(named name: String, toSize size: CGSize) -> SKTexture {
    let image = UIImage(named: name)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    guard let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
      fatalError("Image could not be drawn.")
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return SKTexture(image: resultImage)
  }

}
```

You can use it by doing:

```
let texture = SKTexture.x_repeatableTexture(named: textureName, toSize: size)
```

This solution allows to use slices done in the assets editor, which is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

The better and simpler way is certainly via `SKShader`. A shader as simple as this does:

```
// SpriteTiled.fsh

//uniform vec2 u_offset;
//uniform vec2 u_tiling;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = v_tex_coord.xy + u_offset;
    vec2 phase = fract(uv / u_tiling);
    vec4 current_color = texture2D(u_texture, phase);

    gl_FragColor = current_color;
}
```

Then set the `shader` property of your `SKSpriteNode` with:

```swift
shader = SKShader(
    named: "SpriteTiled", 
    uniforms: [
        // e.g., 0 has no effect and 1 will offset the texture by its whole extent
        SKUniform(name: "u_offset", vectorFloat2: vector_float2(0, 0)),
        // e.g., 0.5 will repeat the texture twice, 1 produces no effect, and 1 < "zooms in" on the texture
        SKUniform(name: "u_tiling", vectorFloat2: vector_float2(0.5, 0.5))
    ]
)
```

if your source texture isn't square, then simply multiply the first component of the value passed to `u_tiling` by the aspect ratio of your texture.