# Sprite Kit tile SKTexture with CIFilter ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, core-image

I am trying to tile an `SKTexture` on a `SKSpriteNode`. From what I see this is not directly possible as answered here : 
[How do you set a texture to tile in Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963513/how-do-you-set-a-texture-to-tile-in-sprite-kit)

Upon checking the reference I noticed that `SKTexture` has a `textureByApplyingCIFilter` method.

How could this be used to tile a certain `SKTexture`?

This is what I have tried:

```
SKTexture *tile = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"tile"];
CIFilter *tileTransform = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTile" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, conveyorTexture, nil ];
CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[tile setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&xform
                                  objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)]
            forKey:@"inputTransform"];
tile = [tile textureByApplyingCIFilter:tileTransform];
```

Also what would be the memory consequences of using this solution as opposed to using multiple `SKSpriteNode` objects with the same `SKTextures` ?

Comment: Well, more memory can be calculated: texture width * height * (color depth bits / 8) ... and time to process the textures. Gains: possibly smaller bundle size.

Comment: So in that case the whole generated image would be in live memory? If for example we load a single SKTexture into memory (the tile) and then create a bunch of SKSpriteNode objects that reference that texture the live memory would be only the SKTexture(with it's single tile) and the other SKSpriteNode objects which reference the single tile ? As opposed to having a big SKSpriteNode object which contains a huge live memory eating image because the pixel data is just copied ?

Comment: Whether you have one sprite or 100 using the same texture doesn't matter memory-wise, regardless of how the texture is created. The CIFiltered texture will probably create a copy of the original texture, duplicating its memory footprint. Easy to check with Instruments.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I just can't get the CIFilter code to work in order to duplicate the image to test it out. I think it could be useful in some situations but I can't seem to find a code example for this particular case. I think it can be used to make my code for this more robust http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040217/spritekit-conveyor-belt

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an `SKSpriteNode`, set its texture, and set its `filter` property to your CIFilter. The `inputImage` property of the Filter is automatically set to the SKSpriteNode's texture. But remember to set its property `shouldEnableEffects` to YES.