# Can you draw a texture without an SKSprite to the scene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

The reason for the question is -- is it better to composite a texture at runtime (and make a sprite on that), or just use multiple sprites?

Example: Say you have a small image source for a repeating pattern, where you need many sprites to fill the view (as in a background).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SKTexture` is just image data. A `SKSpriteNode` is a display object.

The quick answer is no, you cannot draw a `SKTexture` to the screen without `SKSpriteNode`.

This answer goes over that limitation : [How do you set a texture to tile in Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963513/how-do-you-set-a-texture-to-tile-in-sprite-kit)

However, I wanted to answer to give you an option to achieve your ultimate goal.

What you could do is use an `SKNode` as a container for however many `SKSpriteNode`s you need to create your background. Then using the `SKView` method `textureFromNode` you can create one single `SKTexture` from that `SKNode`, that you can use to create a single `SKSpriteNode` for your background.

Hopefully upcoming version of SpriteKit for iOS 8 has some better tiling options.

**Update**

Also, in doing some research tonight, since I had a need for this same functionality, I found this :

http://spritekitlessons.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/tile-a-background-image-with-sprite-kit/

Which is doing similar to what I was pondering doing. Gonna copy the code here, in case that page ends up gone :

```
CGSize coverageSize = CGSizeMake(2000,2000); //the size of the entire image you want tiled        
CGRect textureSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); //the size of the tile.         
CGImageRef backgroundCGImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_to_tile"].CGImage; //change the string to your image name         
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(coverageSize.width, coverageSize.height));         
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();         
CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, textureSize, backgroundCGImage);         
UIImage *tiledBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();         
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();         
SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithCGImage:tiledBackground.CGImage];         
SKSpriteNode *backgroundTiles = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];         
backgroundTiles.yScale = -1; //upon closer inspection, I noticed my source tile was flipped vertically, so this just flipped it back.         
backgroundTiles.position = CGPointMake(0,0);         
[self addChild:backgroundTiles];
```

Comment: Thank you. That is an answer, and I can live with the presented alternative you gave. : (I wasn't expecting the same level of control as in DirectX, et. al. but I thought /maybe/ there was a bit more control available.)

Comment: Updated answer with a solution I found. I was just getting ready to dig in with `CGImageRef` to create a solution and figured I'd google first in case someone had the same idea. bingo.

Comment: For an impl that does not use so much memory, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37768928/763355